# var myArray =[], name;?

Tags: javascript

What purpose does name have in the following statement?

```
var myArray =[], name;
```

I usually initialize my arrays as the following:

```
var myArray =[];
```

Answer (score 18):

It is shorthand to

```
var myArray =[];
var name;
```

It is matter of [personal preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript).

Comment: this is not technically true, is it?  Wouldn't the scoping of name be global even if it were defined in a function?

Comment: @ShaneBlake absolutely not - exactly the opposite in fact.

Comment: @ShaneBlake - As long as `name` is declared with `var` it will be scoped within the current scope be it global or function.

Comment: @ShaneBlake, the style of writing in these two ways doesn't impact anything about the scope.

Comment: Downvoter, would you please let me know why it was downvoted so that it can be improved/corrected?

Answer (score 11):

You are actually initialising two variables there, `myArray` and `name`.

You set `myArray` to `[]` and `name` to `undefined`, because you don't give any value.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var myArray = [];
var name;
```

Answer (score 8):

It is equal to this:

```
var myArray =[];
var name;
```

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript multiple variable assignments can be separated by commas, eliminating the need for repetitive var statements.

```
var myArray = [];
var name;
```

is equivalent to

```
var myArray = [], name;
```

Answer (score 7):

This is equivalent to

```
var myArray =[];
var name;
```

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't affect `myArray`, it's just the same thing as

```
var myArray = [];
var name;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially the instantiation of a second variable `name` with no value.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way (clean and short as possible) of writing this kind of code is the following:

```
var myArray = [],
    name;
```