# Catching checkbox changes and indexing to toggle LEDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like to catch a checkbox change and also catch the index of the checkbox selected or unselected. I'm wondering if this could be ok.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (i) {
    //my code here
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        break;
      case 1:
        break;
          .
          .
    }
  });
});
```

**My html is something like this:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id='led' bgcolor=#cccccc>OFF</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='led' bgcolor=#cccccc>OFF</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='led' bgcolor=#cccccc>OFF</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

So I would like to detect what box was selected and then change the led to ON and to red background color. On the other hand if the the box is unselected I want to return the LED to OFF and change color to `#cccccc`

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your code,     `)};` should be `});`.

Comment: you can access you checked/unchecked checkbox using `$(this)` inside your `$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {});`

Comment: What's your HTML? And, to second [charlieftl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851894/catching-chekbox-change-and-index#comment22559002_15851894), without knowing your objective we can't provide a coherent/sensible answer or suggestions.

Comment: what is objective? there are much easier approaches. Provide more details on use case and what you want to know about the checkboxes. A demo in jsfiddle.net always helps get better responses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without further details, this is the most generic code I can offer (with more information comes great, uh, answers):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    // caching the $(this) jQuery object, since we're using it more than once:
    var that = $(this),
         // index of element with regard to its sibling elements:
        index = that.index(),
        // index with regard to other checkbox elements:
        checkboxIndex = that.index('input:checkbox');

        if (this.checked){ // this.checked evaluates to a Boolean (true/false)
            // this block executed only if the checkbox *is* checked
        } else {
            // this block executed only if the checkbox is *not* checked
        }
});
```

**Edited** to address requirements in (edited/clarified) question:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that),
        led = $that.closest('tr').find('td:first-child');
    led.removeClass('on off').addClass(function(){
        return that.checked ? 'on' : 'off';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xZeTh/1/).

Coupling the above jQuery with the following CSS:

```
.led,
.led.off {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.led.on {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='led'>OFF</td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='' value='' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='led'>OFF</td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='' value='' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='led'>OFF</td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' name='' value='' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I've replaced the `id="led"` wtih `class="led"`, since an `id` ***must be unique within the document.*** This is important, when it comes to JavaScript, and HTML validity.

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: +1; However, to make sure you're aware, the biggest issue is that you're creating one local variable (`that`) and two global variables (`index` and `checkboxIndex`).

Also, if you do go with the option of wrapping `this` into a jQuery object, you might as well use it in place of `this.checked` (eg `that.prop('checked')`, to make sure `this` wasn't modified someplace else.

Comment: Where am I creating global variables? All the variables follow the `var` declaration, in the local scope. Or am I missing/misunderstanding something? And I dislike using `that.is(':checked')` and `that.prop('checked')`, simply because it's needlessly expensive (even though I've not cached the `this` node).

Comment: Yes they are all local variables

Comment: @electronixG: no they are not all local variables -- `var a=1,b=2,c=3;` is not the same as `var a=1;var b=2;var c=3;`  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7384541/183181

Comment: @DavidThomas: the point is, if you're going to wrap `this` in a jQuery object, then it's easier to maintain that code if you use the jQuery object elsewhere, yes it is more expensive, but you confuse someone who comes behind you by using `that`,`this`,and `$(this)` all over the place and you've already created most of the overhead (expense) when you chose to use jQuery in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do if a checkbox is checked or not using this inside your each function code:

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: why even create a new variable? `if(this.checked){...}`

Comment: Sorry, where is the new variable here?

Comment: I *think* s/he's referring to the use of the jQuery-wrapped `$(this)`, rather than using `this`; since `this.checked` returns the same Boolean value as `$(this).is(':checked')`. But, honestly, I'm guessing.

Comment: Right, please excuse my wrong choice of words.  `$(this)` is creating a new object, technically there are functions/variables within that object, but that's not what I meant.  I was merely getting to the fact that `this.checked` is a lot less expensive than `$(this).prop('checked')`

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
      // your code here
      alert(this.value);
   }
});
```