# jQuery more variables semicolon or comma - basic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can just use one `var` for many variables and use comma to separate them

```
var text1 = 'abc',
    text2 = 'bcd',
    text3 = 'dfg'
```

but if my variables are

```
var text1 = 'abc',
    text2 = 'bcd',
    text3 = 'dfg',
    text4 = $(this).find('div').next('li');
    text5 = $(this).find('div2').next('li2');
```

I found comma at the end of text4 is not correct, if the case like that do we still need comma to separate or semicolon with a `var` in the front?

Comment: Why do you think comma at the end of `text4` line is incorrect?

Comment: What you wrote makes `text5` a global variable instead of local, because it has no `var` declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var var1 = val1,
    var2 = val2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var var1 = val1;
var var2 = val2;
```

Commas are for separating multiple variable declarations within one `var` statement, semicolons are for separating multiple statements. So when you use semicolon, you have to use the `var` keyword again because you're starting a new statement.

If you use a semicolon and don't use the `var` keyword in the new statement, you'll be assigning a global variable, not declaring a local one.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a visual answer; JavaScript interprets your code like this:

```
var text1 = 'abc',
    text2 = 'bcd',
    text3 = 'dfg',
    text4 = $(this).find('div').next('li');

text5 = $(this).find('div2').next('li2');
```

This is a great example of a semantic error, meaning that your code is syntactically correct but does not do what you meant. Importantly, JavaScript will make `text5` a global variable because it was declared without `var`.

See these two SO questions for more information:

1. [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)
2. [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript)