# javascript scope : retain global variable value after a function

Tags: javascript

When the 'hypotenuse' function is called the value of 'x' changes from 1. Fix it so that 'x' is still 1 in the gobal scope.

```
  var x = 1;
  var y = 1;

  function hypotenuse(a , b) {
    var cSquared = a * a + b * b;
    x = Math.sqrt(cSquared);
    return x;
  }

  hypotenuse(x, y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do to make this happen is redeclare the x variable using `var` within the function. This is will declare the `x` variable within the scope of the function, leaving the original, globally scoped `x` variable untouched:

```
  var x = 1;
  var y = 1;

  function hypotenuse(a , b) {
    var cSquared = a * a + b * b,
        x = Math.sqrt(cSquared);
    return x;
  }

  hypotenuse(x, y);
```

Or, using the code style which you originally adopted (splitting out `var` declarations):

```
  var x = 1;
  var y = 1;

  function hypotenuse(a , b) {
    var cSquared = a * a + b * b;
    var x = Math.sqrt(cSquared);
    return x;
  }

  hypotenuse(x, y);
```

For more detailed info on what is happening here, read up on *javascript scope*

Comment: @BernardoBaalen, replaced `;` with `,` in line `var cSquared`

Comment: Yeah, that would do the same thing. The only difference is the first code block in the answer uses var twice. See [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: That is not a very good article on scope in general. It is targeted to one very specific scope issue that people often run into (and an examination of how a number of libraries handle normalizing it for you).

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah that's fair enough. Could you recommend a better one if you know of one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var x = 1;
  var y = 1;

  function hypotenuse(a, b) {
    var cSquared = a * a + b * b;
    var x = Math.sqrt(cSquared);
    return x;
  }

  //console.log(hypotenuse(x, y));
  //console.log('x = ' + x);
```

Comment: How your answer is different from already given answer by @JoshDavenport?

Comment: I send my response 40 sec before editing @JoshDavenport. In first answer he give only comma, then he give var x. In Stack Overflow folks  answer very fast :)

Comment: The result is the same, with the comma or without the comma

Comment: @lukpaw, thats fair enough +1 for that

Comment: JoshDavenport yes, you are right! I only explained @Satpal why I sent my answer. I give another way to reach the same.