# What is this variable type called?

Tags: javascript

I was looking though the [CivClicker game](http://dhmholley.co.uk/civclicker.html) code and I found that he created variables with little "sub variables" inside it. It doesn't look like an array to me.

An example of the variable initialization:

```
// Initialise Data
var food = {
    name:'food',
    total:0,
    increment:1,
    specialchance:0.1
},
wood = {
    name:'wood',
    total:0,
    increment:1,
    specialchance:0.1
},
stone = {
    name:'stone',
    total:0,
    increment:1,
    specialchance:0.1
},
skins = {
    name:'skins',
    total:0,
},
```

He later calls the variables using:

```
food.total++;
```

And so on. If anyone has any information on this type of variable then I will be very greatful :)

Comment: Those are JavaScript `objects` -- and the objects have `properties`.  This is basic JavaScript 101 type stuff.

Comment: I must have skipped past that bit xP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are JavaScript objects. The `{ .. }` syntax is known as literal notation and is one way of creating an object. The attributes between the braces are properties, or methods if the value is a function.

The objects are created using the shorthand `var` syntax, which is the same as repeating `var`:

```
var a = {}, b = {};
// same as
var a = {};
var b = {};
```

There are other ways of creating objects and setting properties, such as:

```
var food  = new Object();
food.total = 0;
food['name'] = 'food';
```

You can also instantiate a function to create an object, whereby the function acts like a class.

```
function Food {
    this.total = 0;
    this.name = '';
}

var f = new Food();
f.total = 5;
f.name = 'abc';
```

[MDN Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) is a good resource that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(typeof {test: 0});
```

will give you "object"

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted show 4 Objects, the property total would be a number in this case.

Answer (score 0):

food here is

```
{
    name:'food',
    total:0,
    increment:1,
    specialchance:0.1
}
```

wood is

```
{
    name:'wood',
    total:0,
    increment:1,
    specialchance:0.1
}
```

In JavaScript multiple variables can be initialized in this way.

More info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Examples

Edit: The comments in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript#answer-694165) gives some benefits of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

These are objects.

In programming you can define your own objects to store information about a particular thing.

ie. if you need to store information about a car using code you might create the following object containing a set of paramaters or variables which describe the car.

```
car = {
 color = "red",
 type = "sports car"
 wheels = 4
}
```

The purpose of this is to make organizing information easier, ie you can access the paramaters of the car by using `car.color` or `car.wheels`.

You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp