# Assignment of one variable to two values?

Tags: javascript, variables

I checked out a [github project](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) recently, and I found the following code in one of the files:

```
var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimpFileupload'),
      template;
```

It seems like this is assigning one variable to two values.  What is it actually doing?  Someone in my office mentioned that it may be the equivalent of just saying:

```
var f = $('#some-id').data('string');
var template;
```

Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your colleague is correct: you are declaring two variables, and assigning only to the first. The two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Weird way to do it tho, didn't knew that was even possible.

Comment: Is this preferred for some reason?  It seems somewhat inane.

Comment: @alex0112: There is no advantage or disadvantage from a programmatic point of view. However, the style guide you are following might dictate a certain way to declare variables.

Comment: It saves you having to write `var` a lot I guess. Seems like a matter of personal preference really as to whether or not you use it. This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript) argues for the second way (each `var` separately).

Answer (score 0):

The declaration is not uncommon, quite common in fact, its a requirement of JSLint, to have a single var , and all the variables declared at the top as it would be done by hoisting anyways (but not necesserily in a single line).

On the other hand, there's a well accepted [convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) for declaring the variables in separate lines, sorted alphabetically. The declaration you see is passing JSLint check and adhering to convetion