# Shorter way to declare multiple variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a faster/more efficient way of declaring multiple variables in react native? Instead of

```
let foo = 'foo';
let bar = 'bar';
let foobar = 'foobar';
```

Obviously not problem for three variables, but for bigger sets of variables, is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Faster"? You've determined there's a performance bottleneck here?!

In any case, you can declare multiple variables:

```
let foo    = 'foo'
  , bar    = 'bar'
  , foobar = 'foobar'
  ;
```

But this is simply JS syntax–is this what you  are really asking?

If you have a "large" number of related variables the problem may be more systemic, and there are multiple types of refactorings that might help.

Updated: I used to declare variables like this; I don't anymore.

Comment: Not really a performance bottleneck, so much as saving time not having to type 'let' more than a handful of times. 

And I know it's basic javascript variable declaration, but was unaware if the syntax was the same in react native / jsx, and googling really didn't turn up much.

Comment: That was a lot of extra for a very simple answer, don't you think?

Comment: @SeanLindo Oh yeah. And I could have done more. Not that I spend an inordinate amount of time thinking about syntax and code aesthetics and whatnot :D ... :/ ... :'(

Comment: hi, may I ask why you don't declare variable like this anymore?

Comment: @aanhlle Just don’t; switched to multiple `let` statements. At the time I wrote this I was writing more Elixir than JS.

Answer (score 18):

This is more of a general JS syntax question.

Depending on your use case, you can just destructure an array as such:

`const [ foo, bar, foobar ] = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar' ]`

Note that these are constants, having a lot of variables in a scope makes it poorly readable. See [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-reasonably-pure-functional-programming/) for more

Comment: (I'm not convinced destructuring for destructuring's sake is the clearest code--it really separates the reference and its value and forces a fair amount of cognitive overhead if the number of refs is high.)

Comment: IMHO the solution is not to avoid destructuring, but to avoid the high number of refs. However, this makes destructuring much less needed.