# What does this shorthand mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In this code, what does 'q--' mean in the while loop?

```js
getTotal: function () {
 
      var q = this.getItemCount(),
          p = 0;
 
      while (q--) {
        p += basket[q].price;
      }
 
      return p;
}
```

Is this JS shorthand?  Is there an online tool that converts shorthand JavaScript into longhand?  Also, why are vars q and p declared this way instead of defining them this way:

var q = this.getItemCount();
var p = 0;

Comment: That's the post-decrement operator, common to many languages that copied C syntax.

Comment: `--` means decrementing. It will subtract 1 from `q` with every loop. `q--` == `q = q-1`

Comment: [Here is a handy reference for JavaScript expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: @leok: the loop is fine so long as `q` is an int and `q>0` at the start.

Comment: This should explain your "--" question a little ways down the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript and this should help with your var question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [decrement operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).  The value of `q` is decreased by 1 each time `q--` is evaluated but, importantly, the value is returned *before* the decrement.

So, the loop above will continue until `q=1` but the value used inside the loop during this final iteration will be `q=0`.

In layman's terms: `q--` means "Give me the value of `q` then decrease it by 1 directly afterwards".

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense.

Comment: Specifically `while( q--){...}` and `for( ; q--;){...}` say to execute the loop `q` times, but within the loop q can be used as a zero based index. It is often an optimization borrowed from C to traverse an array backwards after initializing `q` to the array length;

Answer (score 1):

as you can tell `q` is a variable with the number of items and the `--` is [Decrement Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)) it just subtracts one form `q` until reaches 0.

This is works because in javaScript `0 == false` and it will get out of the loop when `q` reaches 0.

Comment: good explanation of the exit condition...

Answer (score 0):

Here, `q--` means "subtract 1 from `q` and keep its old value `q`". The variables are declared in the shorthand method to reserve the size of the page and therefore its loading time.

Comment: I just knew that someone will add whole answer to this trivial problem xD Grtz

Comment: no, `q-1` "returns" `q-1`, `q--` "returns" `q`...