# Variable values are populating incorrectly while multiple declaration

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript basics. While doing multiple variable declaration in a single statement, getting different results.

```js
var jhon, kate = " kate";
console.log(jhon + kate);
var jhon = "jhon ", kate = " kate";
console.log(jhon + kate);
```

Question : Why first console.log prints value for kate not for jhon?

Comment: You might want to check this question for declaring multiple variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript

Comment: If you want to declare multiple , use `=` not `,` `var jhon = kate = " kate";`

Comment: @hs-dev2MR That's wrong.

Comment: Why @melpomene Explain me , I will appreciate :>

Comment: @hs-dev2MR Try it under `'use strict'`. It only declares `jhon`, not `kate`.

Comment: @hs-dev2MR That'll make `jhon` a copy of `kate`, and `kate` will be assigned the value `" kate"`. Different to declaring multiple independent variables in the same statement.

Comment: @Jack It won't make anything a copy of anything. It will assign the *same value* to both variables. Since strings are immutable, that's fine. If you'd assign a mutable value like an object, and you then mutate that object, the mutation will show on both `jhon` and `kate`, which may or may not be what you expect.

Comment: I got it !!! If I declare like `var j = k = {a:11};` and modify `k.a = 99` => `j.a` will also modify to `99` Right :> Thank

Comment: Oh, right - so when the value is an object, it'll be the same reference passed to both variables, but with a primitive, the same value is passed?

Comment: @hs-dev2MR The main problem is that `k` is a global variable there (or an error under `'use strict'`).

Comment: @Jack Well, *always* the same value is assigned; just with objects, that value is a reference to an object.

Comment: Okay, my bad - thanks @deceze.

Answer (score 4):

Because doing this:

```
var jhon, kate = " kate";
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var jhon;
var kate = " kate";
```

Which is:

```
var jhon = undefined;
var kate = " kate";
```

Which, when concatenated, gives:

```
undefined kate
```

You simply haven't given `jhon` a value in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

> var jhon,kate = " kate";

You defined 2 variables, but you only set value for `kate`. Due to the `jhon` is not set value, when you `console.log` it, it will be print `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

what you want is

```js
var jhon = kate = " kate";
console.log(jhon + kate);
var jhon = "jhon ", kate = " kate";
console.log(jhon + kate);
```

Comment: `var jhon = kate = "kate";` is wrong because it only declares `jhon`, not `kate`.

Comment: got it. but since, what the question is dealing with string and not with arrays or objects, this is also correct right???

Comment: Do you know what `var` does?

Comment: detonates a bomb?

Comment: No, it declares a variable. Please refer to [MDN `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). In particular, `var x = y` declares `x`, but not `y`, whereas `var x, y` declares both `x` and `y`.

Comment: See also this [live demo](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fvbQ4VaG4pCgzuUTdmourLLFIoULBVqESiNUzUnNy8tWt//8HAA).

Comment: if i do var x=y='a', y is a global variable. i don't see anything wrong in declaring a global variable here in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `=` to assign a value to the variable not `,`

```
var jhon = kate = "kate";
console.log(jhon + kate);

// Output will be : kate kate
```

---

Following approach is easily solve your issue which very easy to handle.

```
let
  jhon = 'kate',
  kate = 'kate',
  cena = 'foobar'
;
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

For following a will equal 10 and b will equal 20.

```
var a, b;
[a, b] = [10, 20];

console.log(a);
// expected output: 10

console.log(b);
// expected output: 20
```

Comment: `var jhon = kate = "kate";` is wrong because it only declares `jhon`, not `kate`. Destructuring assignment is irrelevant. If you want to assign different values, separate statements are better: `a = 10; b = 20;`. If you want to assign the same value, use `a = b = 42`. But you can't combine that with a declaration.